# String index and slicing

Tags: python, string, python-2.7

How do I find a string index and slice the string based on that .

**Strings**

My Time1:     1000 days 24 hours
My Time2:     3 days 3 hours

I have written the following pience of code to retieve string index

**Code**

```
x = line
days = x.find("days")
hrs = x.find("hours")
print x[hours-4,hours]
```

Throws me the below **error**

```
TypeError: string indices must be integers, not tuple
```

Passing integer by doing manual calulation will solve this error , but as you can see in the time examples , I can't be sure what would be the index as it would vary based on no of days and hours.

Can anyone advise what would be a good way to approach this ?

**Python Version 2.7**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a colon instead of a comma:

```
x[hours - 4:hours]
```

Comment: OOps my bad , wrong syntax :( Off the topic is `days = x[x.find("days")-3:x.find("days")]` the so called pythonic way of doing it?